# Xamarin forms: Method is left after callunt await client.GetAsync

Tags: xamarin.forms, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I am getting data from a server via Rest API. But Whenever i am waiting for the client response the Methos is left by the Debugger and the Program start loading the GUI even though at this point there is no Data to Display. Im already stuck for a couple of days on it. How can i make the Code to wait for the Response? Iam already using Await

My Method to get The Data:  (Client Call in Line 8)

```
  public async Task<ObservableCollection<Datensatz>> getDataFromAzure()
    {
        string URL = URLForContent;

        _client = new HttpClient();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiKey", PW);

        var result1 = await _client.GetAsync(URL, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (result1.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {

            var result = await result1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var ContentFromJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Datensatz>>(result);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ContentFromJson, Formatting.Indented);

            var filename = @"data.json";
            var destinatioPath = Path.Combine(Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null).ToString(), filename);
            File.WriteAllText(destinatioPath, json);
            App.Database_Main.FillMainDBWithJsonEntrys();
            return ContentFromJson;

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Wait method of the Task. Such as

```
Task result = getDataFromAzure()
result.Wait();
```

You can also use the Thread.sleep(1000) to make the main thread sleep for a while. But this will reduce the function of the application because we don't know how long time the async method need and if the time if more than 5 seconds will cause the ANR.